# why my clause count and where in mysql did not work?

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to make SQL query for my line graph. And I have some problem with clause where and AS. How can i fix this?

```
SELECT lulus 
FROM lulusan, COUNT((pekerjaan) 
WHERE pekerjaan='BL') AS pekerjaan 
GROUP BY lulus
```

in php my admin, no message error, just message that the error in near COUNT

Comment: It should be `SELECT lulus, COUNT((pekerjaan)
FROM lulusan`, voting to close as typo.

Comment: thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Your query has vague syntax, perhaps you need :

```
SELECT lulus, COUNT(CASE WHEN pekerjaan = 'BL' THEN pekerjaan END) AS pekerjaan 
FROM lulusan
GROUP BY lulus;
```

Or you can simply it as :

```
SELECT lulus, COUNT(pekerjaan) AS pekerjaan 
FROM lulusan
WHERE pekerjaan = 'BL'
GROUP BY lulus;
```

The first version will give you all rows but it will only display count where as `pekerjaan = 'BL'` while second will only give rows where `pekerjaan = 'BL'`.

Answer (score 1):

count function in wrong place

```
SELECT lulus ,  COUNT(pekerjaan) AS pekerjaan
FROM lulusan
WHERE pekerjaan='BL' 
GROUP BY lulus
```